# PHP: sending apns inside socket server does not work?

Tags: php, sockets, command-line, apple-push-notifications

This week i experimented with php sockets but there is one thing that does not appear to work.

I want to send a Apple push notification (apns) from within a socket server. The socket server works fine but opening another socket to send a message to apns does not work.

The server socket script i use is similar to the example of php.net. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) The script i use to send a apns notification is the following function:

```
function sendToAPNS($data, $deviceTokens, $pem, $password, $debug=0)
{
    $server = ($debug == 1) ? 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com' : 'gateway.push.apple.com';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/home/testing/pushNotifications/'.$pem);
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $password);

    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://'. $server .':2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
    {
        echo 'APNS error:'. $err .' '. $errstr ."\n";
        return;
    }

    $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $data['message']);

    foreach($data AS $key => $value)
    {
        if($key != 'message') $body['aps'][$key] = $value;
    }       

    $payload = json_encode($body);

    for($i = 0,$max=count($deviceTokens); $i < $max; $i++) 
    {
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceTokens[$i]) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

        if (!$result)
            BPLog('Message['. $data['ID'] .'] not delivered to '. $deviceTokens[$i] .': '. PHP_EOL);

       // ob_flush();
       // flush();
    }

    fclose($fp);

    return true;        
}
```

The following warnings are displayed:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094410:SSL routines:func(148):reason(1040) in /home/testing/pushNotifications/index.php on line 162

Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094410:SSL routines:func(148):reason(1040) in /home/testing/pushNotifications/index.php on line 162
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/testing/pushNotifications/index.php on line 162

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/testing/pushNotifications/index.php on line 162
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /home/testing/pushNotifications/index.php on line 162

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195     (Unknown error) in /home/testing/pushNotifications/index.php on line 162
```

The function works in an other environment though. I have tested it in a php file that can be called from the browser and it sends like it should. I use absolute paths for the certificates so that could not be the problem.

Maybe there is a difference in php since the socket server is called from the commandline. Or maybe it simply is not possible to open another socket stream from within a socket server?

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem can be?

Comment: Well the error is pretty obvious and self explanatory:  Failed to enable crypto. So there is something wrong with php installation on that box.

Comment: @Tymoteusz Paul,  i have this same problem, how i fix it?